# Issue with my program (Python 3.5)

Tags: python-3.x

```
option1 = ['cherry','lemon','orange','plum','bell','bar','7']
option2 = ['cherry','lemon','orange','plum','bell','bar','7']
option3 = ['cherry','lemon','orange','plum','bell','bar','7']

 count = 0
while True:

game = str(input('if you want to start a game press y, if you want to back    out press n\n'))
if game == 'y':
    result1 = print(random.sample(option1,1))
    result2 = print(random.sample(option2,1))
    result3 = print(random.sample(option3,1))
    playercoin = open('playercoin.txt','w')
    coin = 10 - count - 1
    print(coin, file=playercoin)
    playercoin.close()

    machinecoin = open('machinecoin.txt','w')
    count = count +1
    print(slotcoins + count, file=machinecoin)
    machinecoin.close()
if result1 == 'cherry':
    playercoin = open('playercoin.txt','w')
    cherrywin = coins + 2
    print(coins, file=playercoin)
    playercoin.close()
    print('you have won 2 coins')
```

I am trying to create a program that runs a slot machine, but I cannot get the program to recognize when `result1` gets the item `cherry`. It just keeps going with the loop.

Comment: remove the `print`s from `result1 = print(random.sample( ... `, `result2 = print( ... ` etc.

Comment: i have tried that but then it does not print the results

Comment: you are setting `result1` to the result of `print` i.e. `None`. set the sample to result then print it in a separate line.

Comment: `result1 = slot1
result2 = slot2
result3 = slot3


while True:
    game = str(input('if you want to start a game press y, if you want to back out press n\n'))
    if game == 'y':
        slot1 = print(random.sample(option1,1))
        slot2 = print(random.sample(option2,1))
        slot3 = print(random.sample(option3,1))`

Comment: No... `slot1`, `slot2`, etc. aren't defined anywhere and you shouldn’t assign a variable to `print` at all. If you catch yourself writing an `=` before a `print` statement, there's probably something wrong. This is correct --> `print('you have won 2 coins')`

Comment: slot1 = (random.sample(option1,1))
        slot2 = (random.sample(option2,1))
        slot3 = (random.sample(option3,1))
        print(slot1)
        print(slot2)
        print(slot3)

Comment: i tried this and it still won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
game = str(input('if you want to start a game press y, if you want to back    out press n\n'))
if game == 'y':
    # Since you are after one value i.e. cherry why not use choice function
    result1 = random.choice(option1)
    result2 = random.choice(option2)
    result3 = random.choice(option3)
    print([result1, result2, result3])  # You can print them all together

    # Or use sample to get all 3 results at once
    options = ['cherry', 'lemon', 'orange', 'plum', 'bell', 'bar', '7']
    results = random.sample(options, 3)
    print(results)
    print(results[0])  # will print result1
```

Comment: i have tried and it still would not work, could the issue be my if statement? `if slot1 == 'cherry':
        playercoin = open('playercoin.txt','w')
        cherrywin = coins + 2
        print(coins, file=playercoin)
        playercoin.close()
        print('you have won 2 coins')`